# Stop printing when non-comment lines are reached

Tags: sed

I am printing between sections of the following form

```
## FAML [ASMB] keyword,keyword  

## Some text

## END OF FAML [ASMB]
```

I have encountered a problem that occurs when "## END OF FAML [ASMB]" is not reached. I want to stop as soon as lines not starting with comment characters "##" are encountered.

For instance, I want to stop upon reaching "Some code" even though it did not find "## END OF FAML [ASMB]" because the line does not start with "##".

```
## FAML [ASMB] keyword,keyword  

## Some text

## End OF FAL

Some code
```

This is the implementation

```
spc='[[:space:]]*'
gph="[[:graph:]]+"
cmt='\/\/'
ebl='\['
ebr='\]'

local pn_ere="^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|${cmt})[[:space:]]+"
local kys="(([^,]+)(,[^,]+)*)?"

nfaml=${faml:-"[[:graph:]]+"}
nasmb=${asmb:-"[[:graph:]]+"}

beg_ere="${pn_ere}${nfaml} ${ebl}${nasmb}${ebr}${spc}${kys}$"
end_ere="${pn_ere}END OF ${nfaml} ${ebl}${nasmb}${ebr}${spc}$"

sed -E -n "/$beg_ere/,/$end_ere/ {
     /$end_ere/z; s/$pn_ere// ; p
  }" "$filename"
```

Comment: Does the input actually contain 3 empty lines in each sample you provided?

Comment: Yes, as comments go, blank lines are allowed.  Blank lines are to be considered as valid, one when one reaches an non comment line, should sed stop printing. Until of course there is another match for `beg_ere`.

Comment: Have not encountered a problem with `beg_ere`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for non-comment and ignore. e.g.

```
# ...

notcom_ere='^[^#[:space:]]+'

sed -E -n "/$beg_ere/,/($end_ere)|($notcom_ere)/ {
    /$notcom_ere/d
    /$end_ere/z
    s/$pn_ere//
    p
}" "$filename"
```